# ASA5505 and IPv6 over a PPPoE Link

Tags: ipv6, cisco-asa

I see a lot of conflicting information about whether or not a Cisco ASA (5505 in this case) can use IPv6 over a PPPoE connection.

I see official [Cisco documentation making it look easy](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-15973), but I see [plenty of forum posts](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2090344) stating that it doesn't work.

The ISP requires that we use an autoconfigured address for the PPPoE link, as they assign a dynamic IPv6 address to the link itself, and give us a static `/56` for prefix delegation.

Is this possible?

---

Our provider is [Internode](http://www.internode.on.net); and they [provide this guide](http://www.internode.on.net/support/guides/internet_access/ipv6/cisco_routers/) for enabling on an 800-series router. The beginning of the `sh ver` of our ASA is:

```
Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 9.1(1)
Device Manager Version 7.1(2)102

Hardware:   ASA5505, 512 MB RAM, CPU Geode 500 MHz,
Internal ATA Compact Flash, 128MB
BIOS Flash M50FW016 @ 0xfff00000, 2048KB

Encryption hardware device : Cisco ASA-5505 on-board accelerator (revision 0x0)
                             Boot microcode        : CN1000-MC-BOOT-2.00
                             SSL/IKE microcode     : CNLite-MC-SSLm-PLUS-2.03
                             IPSec microcode       : CNlite-MC-IPSECm-MAIN-2.08
                             Number of accelerators: 1
```

Onto what I've tried: I've tried enabling autoconfiguration for the connection, I've added the PD into the ASA, but because the actual PPPoE link requires a dynamic IP I can't set a static. I tried anyway (by using `[delegation]FF::1/128` which random forum trolling seems to be a common configuration for Internode) but from memory the ASA wouldn't let me assign a route to an interface only, it wanted a next-hop, which I didn't have.

---

```
edge(config-if)# show running-config interface vlan2
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 pppoe client vpdn group Internode
 ip address pppoe setroute
 ipv6 address autoconfig
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 nd prefix 2001:44b8:310c:9f00::/56 infinite infinite
 ipv6 nd managed-config-flag
 ipv6 nd other-config-flag

vpn(config-if)# show ip
System IP Addresses:
Interface                Name                   IP address      Subnet mask     Method
Vlan1                    inside                 192.168.161.17  255.255.255.0   CONFIG
Vlan2                    outside                59.167.172.177  255.255.255.255 manual
Vlan3                    dmz                    unassigned      unassigned      DHCP
Vlan5                    Guest                  192.168.64.17   255.255.255.0   manual
Current IP Addresses:
Interface                Name                   IP address      Subnet mask     Method
Vlan1                    inside                 192.168.161.17  255.255.255.0   CONFIG
Vlan2                    outside                59.167.172.177  255.255.255.255 manual
Vlan3                    dmz                    unassigned      unassigned      DHCP
Vlan5                    Guest                  192.168.64.17   255.255.255.0   manual


vpn(config-if)# show ipv6 interface outside
outside is up, line protocol is up
  IPv6 is enabled, link-local address is fe80::462b:3ff:fe7a:d5
  No global unicast address is configured
  Joined group address(es):
    ff02::1:ff00:1
    ff02::1:ff7a:d5
    ff02::2
    ff02::1
  ICMP error messages limited to one every 100 milliseconds
  ICMP redirects are enabled
  ND DAD is enabled, number of DAD attempts: 1
  ND reachable time is 30000 milliseconds
  ND advertised reachable time is 0 milliseconds
  ND advertised retransmit interval is 1000 milliseconds
  ND router advertisements are sent every 200 seconds
  ND router advertisements live for 1800 seconds
  Hosts use DHCP to obtain routable addresses.
  Hosts use DHCP to obtain other configuration.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the advice from [Ricky Beam](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/619/ricky-beam) I opened a Cisco TAC case for this issue, just to see what the official word is:

> Hi Mark,
>
> thanks.  At this time, **the ASA does not have native IPv6 PPPOE
>   support**.  I have not seen it on any future roadmap.  You may want to
>   contact your local cisco team to see if they can submit a request by
>   putting in a business case for you.

(emphasis mine). So no, there is no way to do IPv6 on an ASA using a PPPoE connection, and it doesn't look like it is coming any time soon. I guess they expect you to put a proper router infront of the ASA instead.